# gcloud dataproc clusters update - How to remove a pending update that is preventing a successful command run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

In my google dataproc cluster i tried to dynamically resize the cluster by decommissioning one datanode. Executed cluster update with number of worker to reduce cluster size to 1-master and 5-workers which hasn't completed in more than 2 hours.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.update) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot update cluster 'my-cluster-dev' while it has other pending update operations.
```

I locked my computer and somehow lost the command shell, cluster still shows its in updating state hence, preventing me to perform any operation. I have now spent about 5 hours and still not able to execute any command or access the cluster.

```
gcloud dataproc clusters describe my-cluster-dev

projectId: my-project-id-dev
status:
  state: UPDATING
  stateStartTime: '2019-02-22T12:30:02.084Z'
statusHistory:
```

Can anyone please help me out with the way to kill the process which has got my cluster into stuck under updating state, so i can perform other task on the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

What steps did you take in order to reduce number of nodes in your cluster? It's unclear what you mean by "dynamically resize the cluster by decommissioning one datanode". Are you saying you ran "gcloud dataproc clusters update my-cluster-dev --num-masters=1 --num-workers=5" when my-cluster-dev had 6 nodes and it got stuck into updating state or were there any additional operations that you performed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i ran "gcloud dataproc clusters update my-cluster-dev --num-workers=5" without master flag.
I got it out of the updating state by restarting the master node manually.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. Tried to update the number of workers and got stuck in an "updating" state. Like OP, manual stop/start of the master node fixed the issue.

Comment: This is WAI. Concurrent updates are not supported. The cluster gets stuck in "updating" state because it's trying to gracefully decommission the node you are trying to remove. Restarting master helps because it will interrupt graceful decommissioning and complete the update.